# Optimize SQL queries using GraphQL, Nexus and Prisma

Tags: javascript, graphql, nexus, prisma

I'm trying to apply some SQL optimization for GraphQL queries containing relations. I use Prisma (v. 2.24.1), Nexus (v. 1.0.0), nexus-plugin-prisma (v. 0.35.0) and graphql (v. 15.5.0).

schema.prisma:

```
model User {
  id             Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  username       String
  firstName      String?
  lastName       String?
  password       String
  email          String
  organization   Organization  @relation(fields: [organizatonId], references: [id])
  organizatonId  Int
}

model Organization {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String  @unique
  users     User[]
}
```

When I try to perform a simple GraphQL query, which fetches the current organization with users, prisma generates an SQL query which asks for all of the users' columns even though I ask only for the ID.

query:

```
{
  organization {
    id
    name
    users {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

sql:

```
SELECT "public"."Organization"."id", "public"."Organization"."name" FROM "public"."Organization" WHERE 1=1 LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2
SELECT "public"."Organization"."id" FROM "public"."Organization" WHERE "public"."Organization"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3
SELECT "public"."User"."id", "public"."User"."username", "public"."User"."firstName", "public"."User"."lastName", "public"."User"."password", "public"."User"."email", "public"."User"."organizatonId" FROM "public"."User" WHERE "public"."User"."organizatonId" IN ($1) OFFSET $2
```

For the resolver I use the `t.model` syntax:

```
import { objectType } from "nexus"

export const Organization = objectType({
  name: 'Organization',
  definition(t) {
    t.model.id()
    t.model.name()
    t.model.users()
  }
})
```

As for now, I've found that when using the `t.list.field` syntax with the `resolve` function I can get the requested user fields from the `info` argument, but it seems there is no elegant way to pass that data to prisma client.

```
t.list.field('users', {
  type: 'User',
  resolve(org, args, ctx, info) {
    // info contains the requested fields
    return ctx.prisma.organization.findUnique({
       where: { id: org.id }
    }).users()
  }
})
```

Is there a way to use the data from `info` and query only the `user.id` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a community made plugin that you can use that handles all the heavy lifting: https://paljs.com/plugins/select/